# User interface for QGIS processing scripts

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

Is it possible to add combo-boxes, option groups and similar items to QGIS processing scripts? [The documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) mentions text-boxes ('string', 'number'), file browser etc. I would like to add a combo-box with a list of values - should I make my own Qt from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it the open source way, extend processing with a new parameter type `ParameterEnumeration`.

The [ParameterGeometryPredicate](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py#L1060-L1097) should serve as a good sample. There's also a [gui widget](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/gui/GeometryPredicateSelectionPanel.py) defined for it.

For development you can just copy the processing plugin into your plugins folder and modify it in a safe environment there. Once finished, please make a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) so every other processing plugin out there can use this important parameter type as well.

Comment: Thanks! I will see into it (If I manage, I will make a pull request..)

Comment: If you need help with this, don't hesitate to contact via [mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer) or [gitter](https://gitter.im/qgis/QGIS). The QGIS community is very open.

Comment: Is gitter new? Haven't seen that website mentioned anywhere!